# Running migrator with custom marshaller using whitelist

Tags: infinispan

We are migrating Infinispan from v10 to v14 and we are getting:

`ISPN000616: Unsupported persisted data version: < 11`

This would indicate that we need to run the migrator for our SOFT_INDEX_FILE_STORE. Looking at the sparse documentation  [here](https://infinispan.org/docs/11.0.x/titles/upgrading/upgrading.html#offline_data_migration), there is no option listed other than source and target cache name and location.

This results in 0 byte data file.

Looking at the migrator code and running in debug we can see that it supports specifying a marshaller via "marshaller.class" (only documented under JDBC Properties) but there seems to be no way to include a white list to this configuration.

Has anyone been faced with this situation? I couldn't see how the migrator could take a config file as an option, even stepping through the code. Also tried to extend SoftIndexFileStoreIterator to change SerializationConfigUtil.getEntryFactory(props) to force it to build the GlobalConfigurationBuilder with the right configuration, but the code is not extensible since mostly package or private for many parts.

TIA

Comment: You can find detailed documentation for the StoreMigrator [here](https://infinispan.org/docs/14.0.x/titles/configuring/configuring.html#cache-store-migrator).

Comment: @RyanEmerson, I've read all of that and it doesn't cover my concern, not detailed enough to show how to configure white list with a custom marshaller.

Comment: What Marshaller implementation are you specifying? If you're using the JavaSerialziationMarshaller then it's possible to configure the allow list via system properties, e.g. `-Dinfinispan.deserialization.allowlist.classes=`.

I've created [ISPN-14763](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/ISPN-14763) to add support for specifying this as part of the StoreMigrator properties.